# how to use vs2012 and wdk8 to deploy and test minifilter driver on target os?

Tags: deployment, driver, minifilter

i write my first kwdf driver according **this** http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx. I got nothing wrong.But when i create and build my new Minifilter driver using vs2012, then I don't what to do to deploy and test it on my target os in vmware.

Because in the deployment of kwdf, i can do the deployment following this link page's **Deploying and installing the driver** part says, but in minifilter driver's inf file which is generated by vs2012, i can't find the minifilter driver's hardware ID, so i don't know how to do these setting items for a minifilter driver.

This problem drives me crazy. If u know how to do to deploy and test a minifilter driver in vs2012, let me know please. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From MS page that you're referencing the example HW ID is `Root\KmdfSmall` and it is located under `[Standard.NT$ARCH$]`:

```
[Standard.NT$ARCH$]
%KmdfSmall.DeviceDesc%=KmdfSmall_Device, Root\KmdfSmall
```

For a real hardware replace with an appropriate ID.

Comment: I think that hardware id is for some drivers like wdf driver. In minifilter driver's inf file, i didn't find a hardware id.  Obviously minifilter driver's inf is different from other driver's inf, at lease, vs2012 generates them differently. So should i add a                         `[Standard.NT$ARCH$]`                                                      thing in minifilter driver's inf file by myself?? Or shoud i do the **driver install** settings in the  **Package Property Pages** window differently??